# Restaurant table reservation: MySQL Select should show a list of one table and its reservations

Tags: mysql

I am right now a bit struggling with one problem. I have to make a reservation-program for a restaurant. So I have tables and time-windows. And a user can reserve a table in a specific time-window. Now I want a Select which shows me all time-windows from one table and who reserved it whether it is reserved or not. When not the cells should be empty.

I have these table

```
tables
- table_id
- description

time-windows
- time-window_id
- fk_table_id
- starttime
- endtime

reservations
- reservation_id
- fk_time-window_id
- fk_user_id
- Date

user
- user_id
- name
```

the result should be a list like this:

```
time-window_id | table_id | start    |  end      | user_id   | username
2              |  1       | 08:00:00 |  08:30:00 | 55        | Tom
3              |  1       | 08:30:00 |  09:00:00 |           |
4              |  1       | 09:00:00 |  09:30:00 | 23        | Ben
5              |  1       | 09:30:00 |  10:00:00 |           |
```

With a normal join I only get the reserved ones but i want not reserved time-windows to be listed, too.

Any Ideas how it could work?
Probably its very simple but i cant get an idea how this works :(

P.S.: Yes, the time-windows are permanent (a condition from my customer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your database design slightly: time-windows can be a static table that only defines the times. In each reservation record you then specify the table_id and the time-window_id. With such a design you can accomplish what you want by left-joining the reservations table.

```
SELECT `tables`.*, `time-windows`.*, `reservations`.*
FROM `tables`
JOIN `time-windows`
LEFT JOIN `reservations` ON `reservations`.`table_id` = `tables`.`table_id`
AND `reservations`.`time_window_id` = `time-windows`.`time_window_id`
WHERE `tables`.`table_id`=?;
```

Comment: didnt try your way but the hint with the Left Join solved my problem. So I think thanks :D

Comment: @kruben You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote and/or accept if the answer was helpful.